# xcode selector with webview argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to use NSTimer that performs a selector. On this selector I need to pass a webview argument. I am trying to do it as I use to do with strings but not working. How to reach it? Thank you.

```
-(void)setVars:(UIWebView *)webView{

   ...
}


-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {


        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.60 target:self selector:@selector(setVars:) withObject:webView userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Why not just use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, in you case: `[self performSelector:@selector(setVars:) withObject: webView afterDelay:60];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u use **performSelector:withObject:afterDelay** like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setVars:) withObject:webView afterDelay:1];
```